# Django Check for user in list

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm creating a django blog app where users can add comments to articles.
I want to remove the post button when the user has already commented.

I have a model named article and another one named comment (with ForeignKey to article)

I tried `{% if any request.user in article.comment_set.all}` but that doesn't work. I tried to loop over `article.comment_set.all` but that didn't work either.

Is there a method to do this in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing that in template, why don't you do that in view and send it via context. For example:

```
def view(request):
    ...
    user_exists = article.comment_set.filter(user=request.user).exists()
    context = {}
    context['user_exists'] = user_exists
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

in template:

```
{% if user_exists %}

// do something

{% else %}

// do something else

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Yes that's good, but I don't like it to send so many variables to the template. Is there a way to do it in the template?

Comment: i don't think so. Because comment instance is not user instance. and you are looking for a user in list of comments.